# Can a DAG have strongly connected components?

Tags: directed-graphs, graph-connectivity

It seems to me, a DAG (the directed graph has no cyclic.) is not possible to have strongly connected components (SCC), but it can have weakly connected components (WCC).

The definition of SCC and WCC:

- **SCC**: The SCC is an arbitrary directed graph form a partition into subgraphs that are themselves strongly connected (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)).
- **WCC**: WCC is a subgraph of the original graph where all vertices are connected to each other by some path, **ignoring** the direction of edges (from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-weakly-connected-components-in-a-directed-graph/)).

There are some references:

- [Algo: Strongly connected component](https://rosalind.info/glossary/algo-strongly-connected-component/#:%7E:text=Property%20Every%20directed%20graph%20is,instance%2C%20it%20can%20be%20linearized.)
- [Strongly Connected Components](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/strongly-connected-components#:%7E:text=A%20strongly%20connected%20component%20is,only%20on%20a%20directed%20graph.)
- [Find Weakly Connected Components in a Directed Graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-weakly-connected-components-in-a-directed-graph/)

Is my understanding correct? I tried to search references which have more strict claim, but cannot any. If anyone knows, please point out. A ton of thanks!

Comment: What is a weakly connected component?

Comment: Probably, a single vertex by itself is defined to be strongly connected, so the strongly connected components of an acyclic digraph will just be the individual vertices.

Comment: It would be best if you included in the question the precise definitions you are using of strongly and weakly connected components: that's the only way for us to be able to point exactly why you are wrong.

Comment: MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, JBL, I have added definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every graph has a decomposition into SCCs, and Wikipedia's page for SCCs explicitly states

> A directed graph is acyclic if and only if it has no strongly connected subgraphs with more than one vertex, because a directed cycle is strongly connected and every non-trivial strongly connected component contains at least one directed cycle.

So the truth is that DAGs must have no SCCs *on more than one vertex*, not that they have no SCCs *at all*.

It is trivial to see that all DAGs have WCCs.

Comment: In other words, DAGs only have single-vertex SCC, right?

Comment: @TripleH Yes...

Comment: What about WCC? I think DAGs can have WCC. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @TripleH See edit.